# Virtual particle production in space-time.

Tags: space-expansion

Are virtual particles created within existing space-time, or do they create new space-time for them to occupy?

Answer (score 2):

Space-time is not something that can be created or destroyed. Vacuum fluctuations take place in framework of the space-time - so virtual particles are created within space-time

Comment: Maybe this is a question of semantics, but doesn't the expansion of space and the fact that distance is uniformly increasing between galaxies imply that something is being created in between them?

Comment: in my understanding not necessarily. the "distance" betweens "reference points" can stretch without being filled out - but it's highly speculative...