# Virtual particles contributing to universal expansion.

Tags: cosmology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Virtual particle production in space-time.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12995/virtual-particle-production-in-space-time)

Does virtual particle production contribute to observed universal expansion?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! Your two question seem sufficiently coupled that they should have be together.

Comment: I think this is very well a separate question. It is an classic open question whether the accelerated expansion of the universe (cosmological constant) can be attributed to vacuum energy. The other question, whether particles create their own space-time, is much more speculative.